# cannot get data from object Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

i have a json data like this :

```html
"results": [
    {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "romain",
        "last": "hoogmoed"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": "1861 jan pieterszoon coenstraat",
        "city": "maasdriel",
        "state": "zeeland",
        "postcode": 69217
      },
      "email": "romain.hoogmoed@example.com",
      "login": {
        "username": "lazyduck408",
        "password": "jokers",
        "salt": "UGtRFz4N",
        "md5": "6d83a8c084731ee73eb5f9398b923183",
        "sha1": "cb21097d8c430f2716538e365447910d90476f6e",
        "sha256": "5a9b09c86195b8d8b01ee219d7d9794e2abb6641a2351850c49c309f1fc204a0"
      },
      "dob": "1983-07-14 07:29:45",
      "registered": "2010-09-24 02:10:42",
      "phone": "(656)-976-4980",
      "cell": "(065)-247-9303",
      "id": {
        "name": "BSN",
        "value": "04242023"
      },
      "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/83.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/83.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/83.jpg"
      },
      "nat": "NL"
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "seed": "2da87e9305069f1d",
    "results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "version": "1.1"
  }
}
```

i made it to get data object from Axios , 
when i console.log(this.state.contact.location) , it displayed location object

{street: "2868 avenida de andalucía", city: "gandía", state: "región de murcia", postcode: 43796}

but when i tried console.log(this.state.contact.location.street)
i get error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

here's my code :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableHeader,
  TableHeaderColumn,
  TableRow,
  TableRowColumn
} from 'material-ui/Table';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          open: false,
          contact: []
        }
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then((result) => {
          this.setState({
            contact: result.data.results[0]
          })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })      
  }  

    handleToggle = () => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
    handleClose = () => this.setState({ open: false });
    
    render() {
      console.log(this.state.contact.location)
      //console.log(this.state.contact.location.city) i can't use this
      return (
        <div className="App">
            <AppBar
              title="My App"
              iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
              onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle}   
            />   
            <Drawer 
              docked={false}
              open={this.state.open}
              onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({ open })}>
              <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Contact List</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>To-Do List</MenuItem>
            </Drawer>  
            <Table>
              <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableHeaderColumn >No</TableHeaderColumn>
                  <TableHeaderColumn >Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                  <TableHeaderColumn >Gender</TableHeaderColumn>
                  <TableHeaderColumn >Email</TableHeaderColumn>
                  <TableHeaderColumn >Phone</TableHeaderColumn>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHeader>
              {/* <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
                      <TableRow>
                        <TableRowColumn>{1}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{this.state.contact.name.first}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{this.state.contact.gender}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{this.state.contact.email}</TableRowColumn>
                        <TableRowColumn>{this.state.contact.phone}</TableRowColumn>
                      </TableRow>
              </TableBody>      */}
            </Table>
        </div>      
      )    
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using an index array as string though? `result.data.results["0"]` instead of `result.data.results[0]`

Comment: can you add the part where you are trying to `console.log(this.state.contact.location)` and `console.log(this.state.contact.location.street)` please?

Comment: You code snippet does not use .street. Impossible to give a concrete answer. Add your Console call to your code snippet, please.

Comment: @Sag1v i changed it to [0] , still get error

Comment: @bennygenel 
sorry i revised it

Comment: @iquellis sorry i revised it

Comment: Problem is that you are trying to log before the asynchronous function ends. try checking if `this.state.contact.location` null or not before logging it. can you post the result when you log `this.state.contact.location` please?

Comment: if you log `result.data.results[0].location.city` before you set state in the ajax request, does it show it as expected?

Comment: @bennygenel if i console.log it in componentDidMount() before this.setState
it display what i expected

Comment: @Sag1v if i console.log it in componentDidMount() before this.setState
it display what i expected

Comment: change `console.log(this.state.contact.location.city)` with `if (this.state.contact.location) console.log(this.state.contact.location.city)` and see if it works please.

Comment: @bennygenel it works, data is displayed, but why ?

Comment: Like I said before, you are trying to get the value before the asynchronous function ends. Checking if its null or not lets you wait and then when the state sets logging it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. The reason of the error is the `console.log` itself.

```
console.log(this.state.contact.location)
console.log(this.state.contact.location.city)
```

In the first mount, your `state.contact` is an empty array so that `state.contact.location` return `undefined` and `state.contact.location.city` give you your error. After fetching data from `axios` your data should be there correctly